# Constraints.groovy file not being picked up... (Hibernate + Grails)

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm using Hibernate (*.hbm.xml) with data object (.java) and trying to do GORM validation using *Constraints.groovy ([Grails and Hibernate 2.0.1](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/hibernate.html))

I followed the document above and put *Constraints.groovy file within the folder Java object resides, but somehow Grails is not picking up.

Here's the Constraints (ServerSideConstraints.groovy) File:

```
constraints = {
    name blank: false, size:7..15
}
```

Java Object:

```
package com.example.dos.model;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class ServerSide implements java.io.Serializable {

    // Fields

    private Long id;
    private String name;

    // Constructors

    /** default constructor */
    public ServerSide() {
    }

    /** minimal constructor */
    public ServerSide(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Property accessors

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Nexus getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }    
}
```

Here's my Config.groovy:

```
// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config
// config files can either be Java properties files or ConfigSlurper scripts

// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }


grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination
grails.mime.file.extensions = true // enables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format
grails.mime.use.accept.header = false
grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
                      xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
                      text: 'text/plain',
                      js: 'text/javascript',
                      rss: 'application/rss+xml',
                      atom: 'application/atom+xml',
                      css: 'text/css',
                      csv: 'text/csv',
                      all: '*/*',
                      json: ['application/json','text/json'],
                      form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                      multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
                    ]

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// What URL patterns should be processed by the resources plugin
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']


// The default codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "none" // none, html, base64
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// enable Sitemesh preprocessing of GSP pages
grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// enable query caching by default
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = true

// set per-environment serverURL stem for creating absolute links
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console
    // appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}

hibernate {
    naming_strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer to my question. *Constraints.groovy should be under the same folder as the package defined for the Hibernate model (hbm.xml & POJO).

my problem was that the hbm.xml file and POJO files were using wrong package. I had

```
package com.example.dos.model;
```

but I've put those hbm.xml & pojo file under /com/example/dos/model/dos/, so the package definition wasn't correct. After I corrected like below worked.

```
package com.example.dos.model.dos;
```